# DevTools won't automatically refresh console after saving document on VScode

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I use VSCode for my projects and i have been having some issues with the live server.
The first time I go live with my file it works fine (I am learning JS now so whenever I use console.log it prints on chrome's devtools console). However, whenever I save the file again after any changes, the Sources tab on DevTools opens and the message on the picture below shows up 'DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector.'

I am not sure how to fix this issue. I've tried to uninstall the live server and install it again but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

[Picture of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Mr2.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Not quite sure what the issue is here. Your screenshot is of the Adobe Acrobat Chrome extension, which I don't believe was your intent. If extensions are throwing errors, you might try debugging with all extensions disabled (e.g. using an Incognito window) and coming back to post a new question following the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guide.

Comment: I disabled my extensions and that completely solved my issue! Thank you so much!!